# Por favor ayudenme con este problema Err #1235

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Antes que nada un gran saludo, mi problemas es el siguiente:

Tengo dos tablas "secundarias" diferentes vinculadas a una  tabla "principal", las cuales quiero actualizar cuando se inserte un registro en la principal. Este es mi código:

```
INSERT INTO Secundaria1 (a1, a2, P_ID) VALUES 
(new.Valor1,new.Valor2,new.ID_PRINCIPAL);
INSERT INTO Secundaria2 (a1, a2, a3, P_ID) VALUES 
(new.Valor1,new.Valor2, 0 ,new.ID_PRINCIPAL);
```

El problema viene cuando en PhpmyAdmin, en la interfaz grafica intento hacer esos dos insert dentro de un trigger me dice: "Esta version de mariaDB no soporta todavia 'multiple triggers for the same event'"

Googleando vi que a varias personas se les soluciono el problema usando "delimiter" así que me meti en la pestaña SQL y puso este código:

```
delimiter 

CREATE TRIGGER update_secundarias AFTER INSERT ON Principal
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Secundaria1 (a1, a2, P_ID) VALUES 
(new.Valor1,new.Valor2,new.ID_PRINCIPAL);
INSERT INTO  Secundaria2 (a1, a2, a3 , P_ID) 
VALUES (new.Valor1,new.Valor2, 0 ,new.ID_PRINCIPAL);

END;

delimiter ;
```

Ahora el bendito phpmyadmin me dice:  Sorry an unexpected error happened!

¿Me Ayudarían por favor?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Me parece que tu problema es otro.. estas tratando de crear un trigger que ya existe?

Comment: gbianchi  no bro no existe el trigger hagalo como lo haga no funciona!, ¿ Me ayudarias?

Comment: estas seguro que no creaste ya el trigger alguna vez? el primer error te dice que no podes agregar mas de un trigger del mismo tipo a una tabla!

Comment: Mira en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html ahí explica para que se usa el delimiter y no sé si lo que encontraste en google resolverá tu problema, pero si lo hace, deberías probarlo exactamente como se usa, ya que lo que intentas tiene un error de sintaxis y por eso te sale el segundo error. Luego nos cuentas los resultados, tengo curiosidad. En cuanto al primer error, indica que no puedes hacerlo porque la versión que usas no lo admite.

Comment: Ah amigo, solo uso phpmyadmin. Solo quiero saber como actualizo dos tablas o mas con un solo trigger... No pense que fuera tan dificil, no me acepta codigos de php el SQL. No se que hacer

Answer (score 0):

Te falto definir cual será el delimitador:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_secundarias` AFTER INSERT ON `Principal` 

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Secundaria1(a1, a2, P_ID) VALUES(new.Valor1,new.Valor2,new.ID_PRINCIPAL);
INSERT INTO Secundaria2(a1, a2, a3 , P_ID) VALUES(new.Valor1,new.Valor2,0,new.ID_PRINCIPAL);

END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Probado en PHPmyadmin con MariaDB